# Javascript display the last 3 numbers after the dot fixed(3) not working

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a number which looks number this:

```
800.60000305176541
```

This number changes all the time.

So I'm doing this:

```
var mynumber = 800.60000305176541

var changenumber = mynumber.toFixed(3);
```

This is displaying `800.600` ... I need it to display the last 3 like:

```
800.541
```

How can I do this?

Comment: just curious, but *why* do you want to display the 3 least significant decimals but not the more significant ones? I can't think of any sane use case for this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert to string and do your manipulations.
Please note we are loosing the right most digit due to limits of javascript.

```js
var num = 800.60000305176541;

var str = "" + num
var arr = str.split(".");
var result = arr[0]
if (arr[1]) {
  result += "." + arr[1].slice(-3)
}
console.log(num)
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Why do we need a string in the code? Just curious

Comment: Firstly, you could store the number as string in the first place, so you won't lose a digit. I converted it to string to I could  `slice` the last 3 digits.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to solve it mathematically.

```
800.60000305176541 
800.60000305176000 - 
------------------
800.00000000000541



.00000000000541
    10^10.         X
------------------ 
   0,541 + 800 = 800.541
```

Comment: The issue with this method is that this number changes and it might even have less decimals

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the use case? How is it related to real world?

Comment: Basically I have an interval loop which changes the value every 5 seconds. There's not always the same amount of decimals and the value is not fixed. All I know is that - if (value decimals > 3) { just show the last 3 numbers after the . }

Comment: Where are these numbers coming from? Javascript cannot handle numbers more than 16 digits, so I would be surprised if they came from a node server etc

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).